# Get redis host url from terraform helm_release resource

Tags: kubernetes, redis, terraform

I'm using Terraform `helm_release` resource to install `bitnami/redis` instance in my K8s cluster.

The code looks like this:

```js
resource "helm_release" "redis-chart" {
  name = "redis-${var.env}"

  repository = "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
  chart      = "redis"
  namespace  = "redis"
  create_namespace = true

  set {
    name  = "auth.enabled"
    value = "false"
  }

  set {
    name  = "master.containerPort"
    value = "6379"
  }

  set {
    name  = "replica.replicaCount"
    value = "2"
  }
}
```

It completes successfully and in a separate directory I have my `app` terraform configuration.
In the `app` configuration, I want to get get the redis host from the above `helm_release`.

I'm doing it like this:

```js
data "kubernetes_service" "redis-master" {
  metadata {
    name      = "redis-${var.env}-master"
    namespace = "redis"
  }
}
```

And then in the `kubernetes_secret` resource I'm passing the data to my `app` deployment:

```js
resource "kubernetes_secret" "questo-server-secrets" {
  metadata {
    name      = "questo-server-secrets-${var.env}"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.app-namespace.metadata.0.name
  }

  data = {
    REDIS_HOST            = data.kubernetes_service.redis-master.metadata.0.name
    REDIS_PORT            = data.kubernetes_service.redis-master.spec.0.port.0.port
  }
}
```

But unfortunately, when I run the app `deployment` I'm getting the following logs:

> [ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
> redis-dev-master
> at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:66:26) [ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Which suggests that `redis-dev-master` is not a correct host for the `redis` instance.

How do I get the `redis` host from `helm_release` or any underlying services the `release` creates?

I've tried debugging and `pinging` a specific pod from my `app` deployment.

For reference, these are my `redis` resources:

```
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/redis-dev-master-0     1/1     Running   0          34m
pod/redis-dev-replicas-0   1/1     Running   1          34m
pod/redis-dev-replicas-1   1/1     Running   0          32m

NAME                         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/redis-dev-headless   ClusterIP   None             <none>        6379/TCP   34m
service/redis-dev-master     ClusterIP   172.20.215.60    <none>        6379/TCP   34m
service/redis-dev-replicas   ClusterIP   172.20.117.134   <none>        6379/TCP   34m

NAME                                  READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/redis-dev-master     1/1     34m
statefulset.apps/redis-dev-replicas   2/2     34m
```

Comment: Why don't you try with `data.kubernetes_service.redis-master.spec.cluster_ip` ?

Comment: It sounds like DNS is not resolving for you wherever Terraform is executing. That error message also looks like a Redis thrown error and not a Terraform or Terraform-Kubernetes provider thrown error, which helps to narrow down root cause.

Comment: Yup, @Hackerman, that's what I did, if you write it as an answer, I'm happy to upvote it for someone else who might stumble upon it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you were just using the wrong `attribute` to get that information. Checking the documentation at the [Terraform Registry Website](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/data-sources/service) we can use the
`cluster_ip` attribute as described at the [spec](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/data-sources/service#spec) documentation description.
So you should end up with something like:

```
data.kubernetes_service.redis-master.spec.cluster_ip
```

And finally ending up with the following:

```
resource "kubernetes_secret" "questo-server-secrets" {
  metadata {
    name      = "questo-server-secrets-${var.env}"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.app-namespace.metadata.0.name
  }

  data = {
     REDIS_HOST            = data.kubernetes_service.redis-master.spec.cluster_ip
     REDIS_PORT            = data.kubernetes_service.redis-master.spec.port
  }
}
```